# Não consigo fazer a página LISTAR funcionar em JSF

Tags: java, postgresql, jsf, primefaces, cdi

Tenho o seguinte código que estou desenvolvendo com JAVA JSF, primefaces, postgre, cdi, tomcat:

BUSCARBEAN

```
package controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

import model.basica.RegraExcecao;
import model.basica.Usuario;
import model.fachada.Fachada;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Named("buscaUsuario")
@ViewScoped
public class BuscaUsuarioBean implements Serializable {

private List<Usuario> usuarios = new ArrayList<Usuario>();

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    try {
        Fachada fachada = new Fachada();
        usuarios = fachada.listarUsuario();
    } catch (RegraExcecao e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public List<Usuario> getUsuarios() {
    try {
        Fachada fachada = new Fachada();
        usuarios = fachada.listarUsuario();
    } catch (RegraExcecao e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return usuarios;
}

public void setUsuarios(List<Usuario> usuarios) {
    this.usuarios = usuarios;
    }
}
```

listar_usuario.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Lista de Usuarios</title>

</h:head>

<h:body>
<h:form id="form">
    <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" />
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="6">

    <p:dataTable var="usuario" value="#{buscaUsuario.init}">
        <p:column headerText="Id">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.id}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Nome">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.nome}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Login">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.login}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Senha">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.senha}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Data de Cadastro do Usuário">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.dataCadastro}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Data de Alteração do Usuário">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.dataAlteracao}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Último acesso do usuário">
            <h:outputText value="#{usuario.ultimoLogin}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

    </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Já testei em uma classe de teste main se os dados inseridos no banco estão voltando e estão.

Fiz um

```
List<Usuario> usuarios = new ArrayList<>();
fachada.listarUsuario();
```

e mostra que estão voltando.

Alguém saberia o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Tente alterar o `value="#{buscaUsuario.init}"` para `value="#{buscaUsuario.usuarios}"`

Comment: Olá Articuno. Fiz isso, mas ainda não lista nada.

Answer (score 1):

consegui!!! =DDD

O problema era que em outra ManagedBean eu tinha um listar(), ai acredito que ele não estava conseguindo achar por conta disso. Foi só eu referenciá-la no xhtml do listar que pegou! =D

Comment: Parabéns Annie! Poste também o código alterado pois pode ser a dúvida de outra pessoa.

Comment: Eu não mudei nada no código, só apaguei uma classe Bean onde se repetia listar usuário.

Comment: Obrigada Marcus! =)

Answer (score -1):

Creio que o problema está em `value="#{buscaUsuario.init}`.

Você colocou no value um método que não retorna nada como resposta e por isso os dados não são mostrados na página.

Ao invés disso altere para `value="#{buscaUsuario.usuarios}`, assim a página irá mostrar os itens da lista.

Comment: Eu fiz isso já Rubens, mas mesmo assim não está listando =/

Comment: Aparece na tela "no records found."